# Bootstrapping libraries on EMR using python MRJob

Tags: python, hadoop, nltk, emr, mrjob

### Problem Statement:

I am trying to run a map-reduce job in Amazon EMR using python MRJob library, and I am having trouble with bootstrapping the nodes with the requisite libraries and packages.

### Details:

my sample `python mrjob` code:

```
    import re
    from mrjob.job import MRJob
    from sentClassifier import sentClassify
    import nltk

    .. do something ..
```

There are some libraries like NLTK that need to be imported, and there are some of my local modules that I am importing like `from sentClassifier import sentClassify`

I would like to know what's the best way to bootstrap the EMR nodes so that these methods and packages are available. The code works fine on my local machine.

my sample `mrjob.conf` file:

```
    runners:
      emr:
        aws_access_key_id: ***
        aws_secret_access_key: ***
        ec2_core_instance_type: m1.large
        ec2_key_pair: mykey
        ec2_key_pair_file: mykey.pem
        num_ec2_core_instances: 5
        pool_wait_minutes: 2
        pool_emr_job_flows: true
        ssh_tunnel_is_open: true
        ssh_tunnel_to_job_tracker: true
      hadoop:
        setup:
          - virtualenv venv
          - . venv/bin/activate
          - pip install mr3po simplejson
          - sudo easy_install https://code.google.com/p/nltk/downloads/detail?name=nltk-2.0b9-py2.6.egg&can=2&q=
```

But the job fails.

I have read through the following references and tried all their various approaches, still no luck:

- [MRJob documentation EMR Runner configuration](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/emr-bootstrap-cookbook.html)
- [MRJob documentation Hadoop Runner configuration](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/setup-cookbook.html#using-a-virtualenv)
- [Salmon Run's blog post](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2013/06/mapreduce-with-python-and-mrjob-on.html)

Error Log:

```
    Scanning SSH logs for probable cause of failure
    Probable cause of failure (from ssh://ec2-54-86-50-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com!172.31.19.60/mnt/var/log/hadoop/userlogs/job_201405030101_0006/attempt_201405030101_0006_m_000002_3/stderr):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "obidroidMR.py", line 5, in <module>
       import nltk
       ImportError: No module named nltk
       (while reading from s3://mrjob-   51b9493c1a467671/tmp/obidroidMR.shreyas.20140503.012933.336228/files/STDIN)
       Attempting to terminate job...
       Job appears to have already been terminated
       Killing our SSH tunnel (pid 12909)
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "obidroidMR.py", line 107, in <module>
         ObidroidReview.run()
         File "/Users/shreyas/anaconda/envs/obidroid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 494, in run
         mr_job.execute()
         File "/Users/shreyas/anaconda/envs/obidroid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 512, in execute
super(MRJob, self).execute()
         File "/Users/shreyas/anaconda/envs/obidroid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 147, in execute
         self.run_job()
         File "/Users/shreyas/anaconda/envs/obidroid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 208, in run_job
runner.run()
         File "/Users/shreyas/anaconda/envs/obidroid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 458, in run
self._run()
         File "/Users/shreyas/anaconda/envs/obidroid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/emr.py", line 809, in _run
         self._wait_for_job_to_complete()
         File "/Users/shreyas/anaconda/envs/obidroid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mrjob/emr.py", line 1599, in _wait_for_job_to_complete
         raise Exception(msg)
         Exception: Job on job flow j-2R8G1Q3RIE9ED failed with status WAITING: Waiting after step failed
         Probable cause of failure (from ssh://ec2-54-86-50-115.compute-1.amazonaws.com!172.31.19.60/mnt/var/log/hadoop/userlogs/job_201405030101_0006/attempt_201405030101_0006_m_000002_3/stderr):
         Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "obidroidMR.py", line 5, in <module>
         import nltk
         ImportError: No module named nltk
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mrjob.conf` the required lines for installing the packages may not be where they should be. Things that should be applied for a job that runs on EMR should be listed under `emr:` and not `hadoop:` (which is the config for when running job on your local Hadoop installation.

If it is a simple Linux command like `pip` or `apt-get`, then you should be able to install the packages like this:

```
runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: ***
    ... all the other stuff ...
    bootstrap_cmds:
    - sudo apt-get install -y python-boto
    - sudo pip install simplejson
```

I have never tried to install NLTK specifically, so I cannot help you there, but you should be able to install along this line.

For a potentially more complicated installation, I would recommend `ssh`ing onto your master node with the EMR CLI:

```
$ ./elastic-mapreduce -j JOB_FLOW_ID --ssh
```

and actually try installing the package. If you find a sequence of shell commands that successfully installs the package, then you can simply copy and paste that into your `mrjob.conf`.

Comment: trying it out now. so if I ssh in, I could install packages only in master node or all nodes ? Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: Actually, I should have added that you should create a persistent test instance (with `--keep-alive` option, if you use CLI... make sure you kill that job flow once your experiment finishes) and try to see if you can successfully install the packages that you need on that instance with `apt-get`, `pip`, etc. If you use the same type of instance for your "real" run, then adding exactly the same lines under `bootstrap_cmds` in your `mrjob.conf` should install the packages in all instances. It is just a way to figure out your commands are properly installing packages to begin with.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. Error log: Exception: Job on job flow j-PKIO9JHCITI3 failed with status FAILED: On the master instance (i-b619c2e6), bootstrap action 1 returned a non-zero return code

Comment: Ok. Trying it out now. But still .. Thank you so very much for all your help. elastic mapreduce tool isn't working after installing. Rechecking for my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Given that Amazon Elastic Map Reduce uses [AMI based on Amazon Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-ami.html#ami-versions-supported), I verified that I can install `nltk` on Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03.1 - ami-fb8e9292 (64-bit) using the following

```
sudo easy_install -U pip
sudo easy_install -U distribute
sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk
```

you might try incorporate those 3 lines into your mrjob.conf

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work. Error log: Exception: Job on job flow j-PKIO9JHCITI3 failed with status FAILED: On the master instance (i-b619c2e6), bootstrap action 1 returned a non-zero return code

Comment: Can you get any EMR job working with mrjob? i.e., a test job that doesn't have require any libraries other than the standard Python lib?

Comment: ohh yes. The NLTK is for another project. But without the library my mrjob works (the Soteria one) as all the features are already extracted in the db